# Angular keeps building and reloading in docker container

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, livereload

I have issue with my angular app. Once my docker container is build and container start, app keep building and reloading it in browser.

here is my start command -> `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 500",` I have tried added disabled-host-check it didn't work either.

here is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: dockerfile_dev
        image: web
        container_name: web
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
        ports:
            - 4200:4200
        volumes:
            - web_src:/home/server/src

volumes:
    web_src:
        external: true
```

docker file

```
FROM node:14.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/server

WORKDIR /home/server

ADD package.json /home/server/package.json
ADD package-lock.json /home/server/package-lock.json
ADD angular.json /home/server/angular.json
ADD tsconfig.json /home/server/tsconfig.json

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@12.2.14

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["ng", "start"]
```

Angular cli version is 12.

I am using docker desktop for windows on WSL 2 based  engine. If any file changes it again start building and reloading.

logs from docker

```
web  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
web  | ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
web  |
web  | 14 unchanged chunks
web  |
web  | Build at: 2022-07-01T05:42:50.134Z - Hash: da29a1170afc2a3ec1b9 - Time: 3909ms
web  |
web  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
web  | ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
web  |
web  | 14 unchanged chunks
web  |
web  | Build at: 2022-07-01T05:42:52.176Z - Hash: da29a1170afc2a3ec1b9 - Time: 1620ms
web  |
web  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
web  | ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
web  |
web  | 14 unchanged chunks
web  |
web  | Build at: 2022-07-01T05:42:54.958Z - Hash: da29a1170afc2a3ec1b9 - Time: 2429ms
web  |
web  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
web  | ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
web  |
web  | 14 unchanged chunks
web  |
web  | Build at: 2022-07-01T05:42:56.953Z - Hash: da29a1170afc2a3ec1b9 - Time: 1602ms
web  |
web  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
web  | ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
web  |
web  | 14 unchanged chunks
web  |
web  | Build at: 2022-07-01T05:42:58.480Z - Hash: da29a1170afc2a3ec1b9 - Time: 1184ms
web  |
web  | ✔ Compiled successfully.
```

I hope any body can help with this problem.

Comment: Don't map the `dist` folder in your angular root project into the container as a volume, map your `src` and `node_modules` only and other supporting modules

Comment: @dummy dist folder is not mapped at all, src folder is loaded via volume.

Comment: The only reason why Angular reloads is because it detects some change under the `src` folder, maybe you can check git to see if some process writes a file to your `src` folder or not